# What all git hooks can be called in a bare repository?

Tags: git, githooks

Am I mistaken that only `pre-receive`, `update` and `post-receive` hooks can ever be called inside a `bare` git repository created with `git init --bare` ? Are there other hooks which might become relevant?

Comment: `pre-push` can be invoked.

Comment: @ElpieKay To extend your comment: `pre-receive`, `update` and `post-receive` are used to push **to** this bare repo; `pre-push` can be invoked to push **from** this repo to a remote one.

Comment: I think all these can be called?
`pre-push` `pre-receive` `update` `post-receive` `post-update` `push-to-checkout` `pre-auto-gc`